Minitest array check in indifferent order
assert_equal [ '2e', 'd4', '9d', '1a' ], ids
is a statement to verify what array one is dealing with.  But often, with fixtures, there is no necessarily set order.
How can the test be written to ensure that all elements of the array match all items indescriminate of their order?

Another option is to use Enumerable#to_set.
assert_equal(['2e', 'd4', '9d', '1a' ].to_set, ids.to_set)

This question is similar to: How to assert the contents of an array, indifferent of the ordering. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
